# Set Custom values to seek Bar

Tags: android, increment, seekbar

I want to start My seek baar from base 3 and increment by 2 and max is 9 how to set , i need 3,5,7,9,11. my code is

it not working as i want , please help

```
SeekBar sb1 = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.sBtaxitype);

    sb1.setMax(11);
    sb1.setLeft(3);
    sb1.incrementProgressBy(2);
    sb1.setProgress(0); // Set it to zero so it will start at the left-most edge
    sb1.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
             if (progress < 3) {
                 progress = 3;
                 progress = progress + 2;
             } else {
                 progress = progress + 2; // Add the minimum value (10)
             }

            TextView text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvTaxitype);
            text.setText(Integer.toString(progress));

        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {}

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {}

    });
```

Comment: what is happening in current...

Comment: first is 1 then next is 5 then again 5 , then 7

Answer (score 1):

`setLeft()` is for positioning. A `SeekBar` always starts with a value of 0 and rises to the maximum (100 by default, overridden via `setMax()`).

To get a 3-11 range, call `setMax(8)`, then add 3 to the result of `getProgress()` when you retrieve the current value.

Comment: as u said i used it , it only increment one , Don't getting , m using setleft(0) and max is 8 , now sb1.incrementProgressBy(2) , and in progress increment progress again by 2 , but not getting values as i needed

Answer (score 0):

To move your SeekBar in increments you test for `fromUser` and set the progress to the value you want.
In this example the progress indicator will "snap" to the nearest 10 as you move it.

```
@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser)
{
  // round progress up or down to the nearest 10
  int roundedProgress = (int) (Math.rint((double) progress / 10) * 10);
  if (fromUser)
  {
    seekBar.setProgress(roundedProgress);
  }
}
```